# Let $\alpha: F \rightarrow F$ be a one to one field homomorphism, prove $\alpha$ fixes the prime subfield of $F$ elementwise

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $\alpha: F \rightarrow F$ be a one to one field homomorphism, prove $\alpha$ fixes the prime subfield of $F$ elementwise.

So I already proved that $\alpha$ fixes the identity element and used that to prove that $\alpha$ fixes the prime subfield of $F$ when $Char(F)=p$, which was easy because in this case the prime subfield is just $\mathbb{Z_p}$. I'm not trying to do this when $Char(F)=0$, so the prime subfield of $F$ is going to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. I as going to proceed the same way, let $\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $\alpha (\frac{a}{b})=\alpha(\frac{1+1+...+1_a}{1+1+1...+1_b})$.. but I got a little thrown off because i'm not used to using the multiplicative properties of a homomorphism when there is a denominator involved... I guess I could write the denomoniator $(1+1+1+....1_b)^{-1}$ and go from there but I just wanted to double check with yall, and besides that every time I ask something on here I get some new insight into something so I thought why not. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I also get some new insight form this site, reading so many great answers. I saw [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758671/how-would-you-show-that-field-automorphisms-fix-prime-subfields), by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be comfortable showing that $\alpha(a)=a$ for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. It is now enough to show that $$\displaystyle b\alpha\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=a.$$ Well,
\begin{align}
b\alpha\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)&=\alpha(b)\alpha\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\\
&=\alpha\left(b\frac{a}{b}\right)\\
&=\alpha(a)\\&=a.
\end{align}

Comment: Also, using $\alpha(ab^{-1})=\alpha(a)\alpha(b)^{-1}$ is another fine proof.